# Div to auto adjust to fit responsive background image

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a solution to have a parent div auto adjust its size to a responsive background image while still allowing child elements inside that div. I've used a solution from another thread, but as you can see, the child elements are being pushed down. Any suggestions?

Example:  http://nowicki.nigelyoshida.com/services/

```
<div id="category-name" style="background-image:url('http://nowicki.nigelyoshida.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/nowicki-services.jpg'); background-size: contain; width: 100%; height: auto; padding-top: 65%" class="col-xs-12 page-header-image">
<span>Services</span>
<div class="featured-text">
<h1>Why chiropractic?</h1>
<p>Chiropractic therapy can help maintain a balanced relationship between your musculoskeletal health and nervous system to promote flexibility and pain relief.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please extract the relevant part of your site and put it as a snippet here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited the post above.